# How to serve 30GB of pdf files(static) from server using node.js to Angular front end?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have stored the path of folder which contains files in Mongodb database field but Angular does not take folder outside src in build so can't access files in folder should I send files from node using res.sendfile()?

Is there any way to access files in Angular without copying the folder in assets folder?because of the size I can't put files in assets folder.

Help is required as I'm totally confused and stuck at this problem for over 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to create a web server and serve your files from that folder, assuming you are in a node.js environment you can create web server with express js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

//create a folder named files in the directory put files in this folder.
app.use(express.static('files'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Assets server'));


app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000!'))
```

And you can access the files with urls like this way (You don't need to put in the angular assets folder).

eg url

```
eg:localhost:3000/files/file1.pdf
```

Comment: It's not that simple I'm building a MOOC course platform and there are 2000 courses having total of 90,000 contents which contains videos which are hosted on youtube,pdfs,ppts,etc. and on specific course request I need to send contents of that course.for that I have created course collection and stored path of it's contents in one of the fields but Angular can't access that path as it's outside the src.

Comment: In short you need to deliver your assets from a webserver

Comment: can you elaborate??because I'm really confused!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your problem, but perhaps you can use a symbolic link to link the folder with all your files to another folder (under Angular website structure) that is accessible to your website?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will be helpful

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs')

app.get('/asset/:pdfname', function (request, response) {
const pdfname= request.params.pdfname;
const tempFile = "./public/pdf/"+ pfdname +".pdf";
fs.readFile(tempFile, function (err, data) {
    response.contentType("application/pdf");
    response.send(data);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on Port 3000')
})
```

call url in browser

```
localhost:3000/asset/pdfname
```